# How to get value of Oracle DATE column in C# code that matches SQL Developer's

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g

Okay, I'm trying to get the String value of a DATE column in Oracle 11g to pass along to the UI in a C# app (via WCF).  I want to display exactly what I'm pulling back in SQL Developer to a string variable in C#.  Instead, when I've got a Date column, I'm getting some really wacky parsed DateTime values instead.

Examples:

```
Value in SQL Developer: 26-AUG-75
Value from myDataRow[0].ToString() in VS: 8/26/0975 12:00:00 AM

Value in SQL Developer: 01-JUL-76
Value from myDataRow[0].ToString() in VS: 7/1/1776 12:00:00 AM
```

The Oracle dates [look right](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html).  VS's don't.  Thanks, Ben Franklin and [Edward the Martyr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/975).  What the heck?

The SQL's pretty plain.  I'm obviously changing field names, but this is it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MyDate) FROM
User1.TableOfDates@DateTableLink 
WHERE MyDate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY
MyDate
```

The shared code to throw SQL against the db is pretty plain as well.  I'm going to censor it a good deal here, but it works well everywhere else so far, and I think I've got the important stuff here:

```
internal Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection oracleConn;
...
DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand cmdTemp = null;
string strScrub = "";

// strScrub is magically loaded with SQL, which is, 
// if you grab it with a breakpoint here, after it's 
// scrubbed, equal to what I've written, above

cmdTemp = new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand(strScrub, this.oracleConn);
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader dr = cmdTemp.ExecuteReader();
dtReturn.Load(dr);
dr.Dispose();
...
return dtReturn;
```

That part works.  I only include it here in case there's something from using Oracle.DataAccess that I should be aware of.  Everything's opened and closed and collected just fine.  We're throwing hundreds of commands through it each day in dev, and at least thousands on deploy.

Here's some info from the immediate window for the first value (26-AUG-75), with `dr` now representing a single `DataRow` from the `DataTable` pulled from the code, above:

```
? DateTime.Parse(dr[0].ToString())
{8/26/0975 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {8/26/0975 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 26
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 238
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 8
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 307569312000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 975
```

And with just `? dr[0]` -- which gives the same thing:

```
?dr[0]
{8/26/0975 12:00:00 AM}
    Date: {8/26/0975 12:00:00 AM}
    Day: 26
    DayOfWeek: Saturday
    DayOfYear: 238
    Hour: 0
    Kind: Unspecified
    Millisecond: 0
    Minute: 0
    Month: 8
    Second: 0
    Ticks: 307569312000000000
    TimeOfDay: {00:00:00}
    Year: 975
```

Now interestingly that says it's a DateTime when it's just a Date in Oracle.  Maybe I'm missing something about Oracle Dates...

```
? dr[0].GetType()
{Name = "DateTime" FullName = "System.DateTime"}
```

Anyhow, if I could get to the same value I see in SQL Developer (eg, 26-AUG-75), I'm fine.  I can take that and do whatever I want.

Where is the implicit conversion going on, and how can I get in there a little earlier?

I should add that I can't get creative with the SELECT statement & `TO_CHAR`.  This is all a fairly complex automated process that builds queries based on user criteria.  So changing this SELECT would be a "give a machine a fish" not "teach the machine to fish" answer.  Any field could be a date in this format, so switching on GetType values and parsing some creative way in C# is fine, but changing the SQL isn't.

**EDIT** Using a suggestion from [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9741114):

```
select dump(sysdate)today from dual;
```

Using `dump` in the above SQL, run from SQL Developer, I get:
`Typ=12 Len=7: 119,175,8,26,1,1,1` for 26-AUG-75's row.  So Oracle's got the right date.

Following the conversion instructions found [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9741251#9741251)...

```
119 - 100 "excess" = 19 centuries == 1900
175 - 100 "excess" = 75     years ==   75
```

That's 1975.

Comment: The raw value *isn't* `26-AUG-75`. That's just a string conversion being applied somewhere - possibly by SQL Developer, possibly by the database itself. I'm sure Oracle doesn't store its `Date` values like that. Note that `DateTime` is the typical data type used even for "just dates" in .NET. (I have a date/time library which corrects that, but it wouldn't help you here.)

Comment: I'm saying that your "Anyhow, if I could get to the raw values" is incorrect...

Comment: Well, I'd be happy with the "raw" value too, whatever it is.  ;^)  Thanks; fixed.

Comment: I suspect you're *getting* the raw value - it's just not the value you expected.

Comment: In your immediate window, you are converting the datetime you got from Oracle (the "raw" value) to string and then parsing it back to datetime.  I think that's where things go wroing.  Try (in the immediate window) to type "? dr[0]" and see if that is what you want.

Comment: If you really need to format the date you get from Oracle in exactly the same way as SQL Developer does, there are ways to do that, but I'm not sure that is what you really want here.  Do you want the date as a string formatted the same way as SQL Developer does, or do you prefer the DateTime variable?

Comment: Yep, if I could get '26-AUG-75' in C#, I'd be fine.  I'd rather not have to convert to DateTime and parse out the years -- as Jon Skeet says, I really need to find where the data's going bad, if it is.  Editing question with `?dr[0]` -- which gives the same values.

Comment: If you select to_char(yourdate,'dd-mm-yyyy') from yourtable,... in SQL Developer, what do you get?  (the important part here is to specify the full 4 digit year in the select statement)

Comment: Painfully, I get `26-08-1975`

Comment: @ruffin: Okay, in *that* case it sounds like it may be a .NET Oracle driver problem. Sounds like you may want to raise a support ticket with Oracle. It *could* be that there's something you can put in the connection string to help...

Comment: Quick note - 119 - 100 isn't 1900. It's not clear what the arithmetic at the end is *meant* to do, but it's not quite right at the moment... EDIT: Having read other posts, I now see... but it could definitely be clearer :)

Comment: Check here: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9741251#9741251

Comment: I give up -- I think @JonSkeet 's 2nd suggestion is probably the best for now.  The database doesn't have bad values, just poorly formed ones.  And `myDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")` returns the same whether 1975, 1775, or 775 (minus the outliers JonSkeet mentions).  So I think I can ignore, practically speaking, the wackiness.  Thanks a ton for the help, and learning about `dump` was fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear from your question, but I assume you actually wanted 1975 and 1976?

I strongly suspect that the values 0975 and 1776 are *actually* what are in the database. Your values in SQL Developer are just a 2-digit-year representation of that. I suspect that if you perform a different kind of string conversion which uses a 4-digit-year representation, you'll see the same values.

So, options after validating that the above is correct:

- Work out how the bad data got in the system, fix that (so you don't get any more bad data) and then fix the existing data.
- Work around the issue by ignoring all but the last two digits of the year, and forcing them to an appropriate century. Note that there could be some "interesting" data around in terms of Feb 29th being valid in some years but not others...

I'd strongly suggest casting to `DateTime` rather than converting to a string and then parsing it, by the way.

Comment: That's essentially right.  To be more clear, I want the value I could put into the `WHERE` clause to that original table and get the same row from the database that it originally pulled.  Right now, if I add `WHERE MyDate = '26-AUG-75'` in SQL Developer, I get the row I wanted.  I can't do anything (efficiently) with '8/26/0975 12:00:00 AM'

Comment: @ruffin: I suspect Oracle is performing a string conversion somewhere then... but it's absolutely vital that you work out what data you've *really* got. You should avoid 2-digit year formats everywhere you possibly can.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see what Oracle thinks the "raw" value is?  If it was literally '26-AUG-75', I'd expect Oracle to default to 1975, right?  Agreed on two digit years; afraid the system predates my involvement by a good deal.  But if you asked me if '26-AUG-75' is bad data, I'd probably say it's not great, but no, not "bad", so to speak.  As you say, there's a wack string conversion going on **somewhere**.

Comment: The `dump` test, above, along with the to_char(), seems to suggest it's happening on the .NET side, I think.  I may have to just take suggestion 2 for now.

Comment: Even though it seems to be that the database _did_ have 1975 and 1976 in it, it's still a mystery exactly where things parse incorrectly.  Long term I'll want to follow-up with option 1, but for now option 2 is the right answer, I guess.  Thanks for the help.